# What data type is the following data: "8:5e:ad:55:b:a:c5:30:8:5b:ef:7f:e9:d7:aa:f3"

Tags: sql, types, sqldatatypes

I am trying to understand an SQL database that contains data relevant to a project I am working on. It contains data that looks like this:

8:5e:ad:55:b:a:c5:30:8:5b:ef:7f:e9:d7:aa:f3:4f:cd:e0:9:83:36:a6:31:da:c2:9e:c7:62:69:38:b0:2c:8d:25:ab:c2:60:20:f3:2a:6d:f5:c4:d:4b:46:8e:6c:a5:d:d1:17:83:c0:18:99:e2:f6:ff:27:86:ea:ab:d8:4b:66:b5:9b:dd:de:c5:a6:f5:74:e4:21:22:4d:e7:ca:54:d1:6e:8c:79:aa:c7:e8:a0:c6:69:98:38:76:a2:e5:d0:d2:a4:8:b9:a4:b1:37:8f:a7:74:48:44:44:34:29:9e:43:6d:4:41:de:f4:d4:37:47:3a:6e:93:95:35:c5:5:6d:2b:2b:71:e1:71:82:a:b1:2:7c:b4:e2:5:1:89:62:5:29:2d:d3:2b:95:1a:0:2c:ae:53:6e:24:22:f4:da:9c:7d:a:73:54:fc:d0:4d:bc:ee:9b:32:78:89:f2:7a:6f:4a:3e:7:3d:c:3e:30:cf:47:84:51:4d:b8:a3:f4:2f:30:ff:3f:df:21:2:f6<

Is this data in a particular format? i.e. is there a particular structure to this data/ what do the individual segments mean (i.e. 5e, ad, 55 etc.)

Please bare with, I am relatively new to coding and the different ways in which we can represent data.

Comment: Which database system? The column the value is contained in should have a data type. As for what it means, how it is used, what put it there, how would random internet strangers know? We can only guess or assume.

Comment: One or two hexadecimal digits suggest octets (bytes)... Thus this is binary data, could be in any format...

Comment: You cannot infer type from rendered values.  Want to know the type ?  Look at the definition of the query you got the value from, and the definitions of the underlying tables in terms of which it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The data you have provided looks like HEX to me. Here's a [Relevant Tool](https://www.asciitohex.com/)